# How to properly obfuscate javascript code with javascript2img?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I tried obfuscating JS code using javascript2img. It gave me the obfuscated code. They state, "Copy this code and paste it into your js or HTML file. That's all!". But I keep getting this error.

`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier                           game.js:1"`

Un-obfuscated the code works just fine.

Example: The following doesnt work obfuscated but does without obfuscation.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.AUTO, "gameDiv");

var mainState = {

    preload: function() { 
        if(!game.device.desktop) {
            game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
            game.scale.setMinMax(game.width/2, game.height/2, game.width, game.height);
        }

        game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;

        game.stage.backgroundColor = '#71c5cf';

        game.load.image('bird', 'assets/bird.png');  
        game.load.image('pipe', 'assets/pipe.png'); 

        // Load the jump sound
//        game.load.audio('jump', 'assets/jump.wav'); 
    },

    create: function() { 
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        this.pipes = game.add.group();
        this.timer = game.time.events.loop(1500, this.addRowOfPipes, this);           

        this.bird = game.add.sprite(100, 245, 'bird');
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bird);
        this.bird.body.gravity.y = 1000; 

        // New anchor position
        this.bird.anchor.setTo(-0.2, 0.5); 

        var spaceKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
        spaceKey.onDown.add(this.jump, this); 
        game.input.onDown.add(this.jump, this);

        this.score = 0;
        this.labelScore = game.add.text(20, 20, "0", { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" });  

        // Add the jump sound
        this.jumpSound = game.add.audio('jump');
        this.jumpSound.volume = 0.2;
    },

    update: function() {
        if (this.bird.y < 0 || this.bird.y > game.world.height)
            this.restartGame(); 

        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.bird, this.pipes, this.hitPipe, null, this); 

        // Slowly rotate the bird downward, up to a certain point.
        if (this.bird.angle < 20)
            this.bird.angle += 1;  
    },

    jump: function() {
        // If the bird is dead, he can't jump
        if (this.bird.alive == false)
            return; 

        this.bird.body.velocity.y = -350;

        // Jump animation
        game.add.tween(this.bird).to({angle: -20}, 100).start();

        // Play sound
//        this.jumpSound.play();
    },

    hitPipe: function() {
        // If the bird has already hit a pipe, we have nothing to do
        if (this.bird.alive == false)
            return;

        // Set the alive property of the bird to false
        this.bird.alive = false;

        // Prevent new pipes from appearing
        game.time.events.remove(this.timer);

        // Go through all the pipes, and stop their movement
        this.pipes.forEach(function(p){
            p.body.velocity.x = 0;
        }, this);
    },

    restartGame: function() {
        game.state.start('main');
    },

    addOnePipe: function(x, y) {
        var pipe = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'pipe');
        this.pipes.add(pipe);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(pipe);

        pipe.body.velocity.x = -200;  
        pipe.checkWorldBounds = true;
        pipe.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    },

    addRowOfPipes: function() {
        var hole = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            if (i != hole && i != hole +1) 
                this.addOnePipe(400, i*60+10);   

        this.score += 1;
        this.labelScore.text = this.score;  
    },
};

game.state.add('main', mainState);  
game.state.start('main');
```

Comment: The code you posted converts fine for me. You'll have to be more specific than "it doesn't work". Also please note that javascript2img is NOT proper obfuscation, I can easily decode it using [this, for example](https://gist.github.com/vthibault/bb30dcda2f61dc6addbf)

Comment: how can i obfuscate it properly then please? I didn't know it could be easily decoded - that defeats the purpose of it for me now. I have read through everything on here on obfuscation and not found a tool or method for decent obfuscation. Pls advise

Comment: Forget this "obfuscation", it's too easy to reverse : https://gist.github.com/vthibault/bb30dcda2f61dc6addbf